# grunt task "uglify" changed the JavaScript code and now the source code no longer works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

The grunt task "uglify" changed my code so it doesn't work any more. I’m a beginner with CoffeeScript, AngularJS, grunt, etc. What do I have to change on my CoffeeScript code in order to fix this?

I have no clue why the "uglify" changed my code like that. The JavaScript code looks good to me.

**CoffeeScript code:**

```
# add background and some style just for specific page
.directive('customBackground', () ->
  return {
  restrict: "A"
  controller: [
    '$scope', '$element', '$location'
    ($scope, $element, $location) ->
      path = ->
        return $location.path()

      addBg = (path) ->
        # remove all the classes
        $element.removeClass 'body-home body-special body-tasks body-lock'

        # add certain class based on path
        switch path
          when '/' then $element.addClass 'body-home'
          when '/404', '/500', '/signin' then $element.addClass 'body-special'

      addBg $location.path()

      $scope.$watch(path, (newVal, oldVal) ->
        if newVal is oldVal
          return
        addBg $location.path()
        return
      )
      return
  ]
  }
)
```

**compiled JS code**

```
.directive('customBackground', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      controller: [
        '$scope', '$element', '$location', function($scope, $element, $location) {
          var addBg, path;
          path = function() {
            return $location.path();
          };
          addBg = function(path) {
            $element.removeClass('body-home body-special body-tasks body-lock');
            switch (path) {
              case '/':
                return $element.addClass('body-home');
              case '/404':
              case '/500':
              case '/signin':
                return $element.addClass('body-special');
            }
          };
          addBg($location.path());
          $scope.$watch(path, function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal === oldVal) {
              return;
            }
            addBg($location.path());
          });
        }
      ]
    };
  })
```

**JS code after the "uglify" task**

```
.directive("customBackground", function () {
    return{restrict: "A", controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$location", function ($scope, $element, $location) {
        var addBg, path;
        path = function () {
            return $location.path()
        }, addBg = function (path) {
            switch ($element.removeClass("body-home body-special body-tasks body-lock"), path) {
                case"/":
                    return $element.addClass("body-home");
                case"/404":
                case"/500":
                case"/signin":
                    return $element.addClass("body-special")
            }
        }, addBg($location.path()), $scope.$watch(path, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            newVal !== oldVal && addBg($location.path())
        })
    }]}
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by `no longer works`? Does it throw any exception?

Comment: I don’t get any exception. The directive just don’t work anymore. Which mines it doesn't change the CSS class anymore. After the path function is a comma instance of semicolon and so on....

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: It works, **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2LVFR/1/, you must check other uglifyied files

Comment: Now, I suspect that other files my contain 'use strict' at global scope.